# Setup hebi robot on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotics

I have a question about runtime error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import hebi
from time import sleep
lookup = hebi.Lookup()
```

At `lookup = hebi.Lookup()`, the error below happened.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                      
File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>                                                                                  
  import hebi                                                                                                         
.....
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hebi\_internal\raw.py", line 394, 
in _init_hebi_library                                                                                                   
raise RuntimeError('HEBI Core library not found')                                                                   
RuntimeError: HEBI Core library not found
```

I'm not sure why HEBI Core is not there. How and where do I install some tools for solving this problem?

Comment: how did you install the hebi library? the error also is happening on the first import line as it clearly says in the error you receive, not on the `hebi.Lookup()` line.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the issues that you are having.

I maintain the Python API at HEBI, and I am aware of this issue (although I just saw this issue now).

A solution to this is coming soon, but for the time being, please download and install the 64 bit version of Python 3 from Python's website ( https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ ) or see the temporary workaround below. Please also note that the 64 bit version is the `x86-64` version - NOT `x86`.

---

If you require the 32 bit Python (or just do not want to install the 64 bit version for whatever reason), you can replace the file at

`C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hebi\lib\win_x64\hebi.dll`

with the file at

`C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\hebi\lib\win_x86\hebi.dll`

However, realize that you will not be able to run the API with a 64 bit Python executable this way.

---

If you are at all curious what is happening here, the (currently) faulty logic is attempting to load `hebi.dll` but fails to since it tries to load the x86-64 version and not the 32 bit (x86) version.